# Could not load the "usflag.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "test.icon"

Tags: ios, xcode, button

I can't find the reason why I get this message:

Could not load the "usflag.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier ...

I create 2 buttons, set the type as custom, select 2 png as the image. Everything works fine in Xcode. It shows up ok with the simulator for the first button and I get the error for the 2nd button that shows up except the image.

I was getting similar effect with Xcode 6.4 and then move to 7 beta 4 with no success.

Any idea how to solve such a simple thing?

I add the source of the main.storyboard:

```
                   <subviews>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="fill" contentVerticalAlignment="fill" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="hFS-FI-nNd">
                            <rect key="frame" x="20" y="28" width="42" height="30"/>
                            <state key="normal" image="french_flag.png">
                                <color key="titleColor" red="0.0" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                            </state>
                        </button>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="fill" contentVerticalAlignment="fill" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="FGS-JR-8HH">
                            <rect key="frame" x="20" y="66" width="42" height="30"/>
                            <state key="normal" image="usflag.png">
                                <color key="titleColor" red="0.0" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                            </state>
                        </button>
                    </subviews>
```

Comment: It's highly discouraged to edit storyboard xml source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :)

for me it's a bug in Xcode.

buttons with image associated need to reside in images.xcassets